# Pupil detection with hough transform

Tags: matlab, geometry, hough-transform

so I am working for my disertation thesis and I have to detect the pupil from images using Hough Transform. So far I wrote a code that identifies 2 circles on my image, but right now I have to keep the black circle from the pupil.

When I run the code, it identifies me the pupil, but also a random circle on the cheek. My professor said that I should calculate the pixels mean and, considering the fact that the pupil is black, to keep the pixels from only that region. I don't know how to do this.

I will let my code here to have a look and if someone has an ideea on how should I write this and keep only the black pixels would be great. I also attached to this the final image to see what I obtained.

close all
clear all
path='C:\Users\Ioana PMEC\OneDrive\Ioana personal\Disertatie\test.jpg';

```
%Citire imagine initiala
xx = imread(path);
figure
imshow(xx)
title('Imagine initiala');% Binarizarea imaginii initiale
yy = rgb2gray(xx);
figure
imshow(yy);
title('Imagine binarizata');

e = edge(yy, 'canny');
imshow(e);
radii = 11:1:30;
h = circle_hough(e, radii, 'same', 'normalise');


peaks = circle_houghpeaks(h, radii, 'nhoodxy', 15, 'nhoodr', 21, 'npeaks', 2);

imshow(yy);
hold on;
for peak = peaks
    [x, y]=circlepoints(peak(3));
    plot(x+peak(1), y+peak(2), 'r-');
  
end

hold off
```

testimage
[image: testimage]
finalimage
[image: finalimage]

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something which should get the task done for you. The example is done with the image you provided.

**Step 1:** Read the file(s) and convert them to grayscale.

```
path = %user input;
RGB = imread(path);
lab = rgb2lab(RGB);
grayscale_image = rgb2gray(RGB);
```

**Step 2:** Do the Hough transformation with given parameters.
These, and also the sensitivity can be adapted according to your task. **Hint:** Play around in the Image Segmenter toolbox for fast parameter finding. Next, the inferred circles are converted to integer values, since these are required for indexing.

```
min_radius = 10;
max_radius = 50;
% Find circles
[centers,radii,~] = imfindcircles(RGB,[min_radius max_radius],'ObjectPolarity','dark','Sensitivity',0.95);
centers = uint16(centers);
radii = uint16(radii);
```

The annotated image appears as follows:
[image: All circles annotated]

**Step 3:** Get the brightness values of the circles.
From the circle center and radius values, we infer their respective brightness. It is sufficient to only check for the x and y pixel values left/right and above/below the center. (*-1* is just a safety margin to completely stay within the circles.)

```
brightness_checker = zeros(2, max(radii), 2);
for i=1:size(centers,1)
    current_radii = radii(i)-1;
    for j=1:current_radii
        % X-center minus radius, step along x-axis
        brightness_checker(i, j, 1) = grayscale_image((centers(i,2) - current_radii/2) + j,...
            (centers(i,1) - radii(i)/2) + j);
        % Y-center minus radius, step along y-axis
        brightness_checker(i, j, 2) = grayscale_image((centers(i,2) - current_radii/2) + j,...
            (centers(i,1) - current_radii/2) + j);
    end    
end
```

**Step 4:** Check which circle is a pupil.
The determined value of *30* could potentially be enhanced.

```
median_x = median(brightness_checker(:,:,1),2);
median_y = median(brightness_checker(:,:,2),2);
is_pupil = (median_x<30)&(median_y<30);
pupils_center = centers(is_pupil == true,:);
```

**Step 5:** Draw the pupils.
The marker can be changed. Refer to:
https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.line-properties.html

```
figure
imshow(grayscale_image);
hold on 
plot(centers(:,1), centers(:,2), 'r+', 'MarkerSize', 20, 'LineWidth', 2);
hold on 
plot(pupils_center(:,1), pupils_center(:,2), 'b+', 'MarkerSize', 20, 'LineWidth', 2);
```

This is the final output:
[image: All pupils annotated.]